# Deleting properties of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to delete properties of DOM elements? I'm using a widget that upon rendering itself adds `tabindex` attributes to certain nodes. I'd like to remove them because they cause unwanted visual changes.

I tried the following which does not seem to have any effect (`tabindex` stays the same):

```
delete domNode.tabIndex;
domNode.tabIndex = undefined;
```

Comment: Also, `tabIndex` *may* be a special case because every element will have an internal tabindex, whether one is explicitly set or not. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I recall, you can use the `removeAttribute` method. So, in your case:

```
[DomElement].removeAttribute('tabindex');
```

should do the trick.